# ionic push notification when app is in foreground

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am making a ionic 3 app. I want notifications to appear even when app is in foreground. I have tried using  FCM Plugin I'm getting notifications only when app is in background.

Home.ts

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import firebase from 'firebase';

declare var FCMPlugin;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  firestore = firebase.database().ref('/pushtokens');
  firemsg = firebase.database().ref('/messages');
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public afd:AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.tokensetup().then((token)=>{
      this.storeToken(token);
    })

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    FCMPlugin.onNotification(function (data) {
      if (data.wasTapped) {
        //Notification was received on device tray and tapped by the user.
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      } else {
        //Notification was received in foreground. Maybe the user needs to be notified.
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    });
    FCMPlugin.onTokenRefresh(function (token) {
      alert(token);
    });

  }

  tokensetup(){
    var promise = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      FCMPlugin.getToken(function(token){
         resolve(token);
        },(err)=>{
          reject(err);
        });
    })
    return promise;
  }
  storeToken(token){
    this.afd.list(this.firestore).push({
       uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
       devtoken: token
    }).then(()=>{
      alert('Token stored')
    }).catch(()=>{
      alert('Token not stored');
    })
    // this.afd.list(this.firemsg).push({
    //   sendername:'adirzoari',
    //   message: 'hello for checking'
    // }).then(()=>{
    //   alert('Message stored');
    // }).catch(()=>{
    //   alert('message not stored');
    // })
  }
}
```

the function cloud for notifications

```
  var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var wrotedata;
exports.Pushtrigger = functions.database.ref('/messages/{messageId}').onWrite((event) => {
    wrotedata = event.data.val();

    admin.database().ref('/pushtokens').orderByChild('uid').once('value').then((alltokens) => {
        var rawtokens = alltokens.val();
        var tokens = [];
        processtokens(rawtokens).then((processedtokens) => {

            for (var token of processedtokens) {
                tokens.push(token.devtoken);
            }

        var payload = {

                "notification":{
                    "title":"From" + wrotedata.sendername,
                    "body":"Msg" + wrotedata.message,
                    "sound":"default",
                    },
                "data":{
                    "sendername":wrotedata.sendername,
                    "message":wrotedata.message
                }
        }

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then((response) => {
                console.log('Pushed notifications');
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })


        })    
    })
})

function processtokens(rawtokens) {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         var processedtokens = []
    for (var token in rawtokens) {
        processedtokens.push(rawtokens[token]);
    }
    resolve(processedtokens);
    })
    return promise;    

}
```

it works only when the app in the background. but when i exit from the app and it's not in the background I don't get any notification.

Comment: Any update on this?
Seems like I am stuck at this too!

Comment: Any Updates on this??? got strucked

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the FCM Plugin files. I found the solution only for android now.

I use https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm this FCM plugin for android and ios in cordova.

You need to edit file MyFirebaseMessagingService.java line 53(line no be may be differ).

In this file there is a method `onMessageReceived` at the end of the method there is a line which is commented, this line calling an another method i.e. `sendNotification(....)`.

```
sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), data);
```

You have to uncomment this line and change last parameter from `remoteMessage.getData() to data` (data variable is already there in the code).

And comment this line `FCMPlugin.sendPushPayload( data );`

Now you are good to go. Now you are able to receive notification even when app is opened (foreground), you will receive the banner (floating) notifications.

If you found anything for IOS please let me know!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using firebase plugin for ionic 3.
There is a check if notification data contain "notification_foreground" or not and save it in variable foregroundNotification.

```
  if(data.containsKey("notification_foreground")){
            foregroundNotification = true;
        }
```

then it create **showNotification** variable which decide if we need to show notification or not and pass this to the sendMessage (show notification function).

```
  if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(body) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(title) || (data != null && !data.isEmpty())) {
        boolean showNotification = (FirebasePlugin.inBackground() || !FirebasePlugin.hasNotificationsCallback() || foregroundNotification) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(body) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(title));
        sendMessage(data, messageType, id, title, body, showNotification, sound, vibrate, light, color, icon, channelId, priority, visibility);
    }
```

your payload should contain notification_foreground, notification_title and notification_body.